# Getting unexpectedly found nil runtime error on NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to get a reference to the cell that a button is contained in when the button is tapped, but it's throwing an error it shouldn't be.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

I'm checking to see if it's optional value is nil and it isn't and then it throws the runtime error..

```
func buttonReleased(button: UIButton){
  let pointInTable: CGPoint = button.convertPoint(button.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
  var path = myTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)

  if let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!) as? MainListTableViewCell {
     println("test")
  } else {
     println("it didn't work, let's think about why")
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Step one: stop saying "it shouldn't be". Listen to the runtime. It knows more than you do.

Comment: fair enough haha. It just seems to be a weird situation that shouldn't cause this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var cell = self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!) 
     as MainListTableViewCell
```

Think about what you know and what you don't know. You know that `path` is not nil. But that's all you know. Your code makes many other assumptions. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns an Optional. You are *assuming* that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for that particular `path` is not nil. And you are further *assuming* that the cell it returns is a MainListTableViewCell. Instead of assuming, write your code in such a way that you *check* each of those things before unwrapping the Optional.

So, you could have written that code this way:

```
 if let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!) 
     as? MainListTableViewCell {
     // ... safe to use cell here
 } else {
     println("it didn't work, let's think about why")
 }
```

Comment: That code just throws a runtime exception, but you are right that I could/should have done it that way.

Comment: Dude. _Your_ code throws a runtime exception. I'm just trying to give you some ideas how to find out why. You do still have to do some thinking. Never mind my code; that's just some stuff I typed in the browser. Think about what I'm _telling_ you about _how_ to figure this out.

Comment: Actually, you don't even really know that path is nil, and, path being nil would explain exactly the problem he's seeing.  As an example, passing a point outside of any cell will return nil.